# Request module python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm having trouble using Python's request module.I'm trying to login to a webpage but it does not allow my connection.I don't really know if it might be a validation problem. Here is the code I'm using and the link of the page. It never shows me the page (The one I'm trying to access after I log in).

```
import requests
with requests.Session() as c:
  username = "*******"
  password = "******"
  payload = {"userPri": username, "password": password}
  url="https://declaraciones.sri.gob.ec/tuportalinternet/verificaEmail.jspa"
  c.post("",data=payload)
  page=c.get("another webpage")
  print (page.content)`
```

Comment: Please provide exact traceback or error message? Which HTTP status code do you get? Did you try [request's Basic Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/#basic-authentication)?

Comment: I don't get an error message, it never shows me the requested webpage but it shows me the one where the login system is. No I'm just using post to submit. The response code is "200"